# POCO and Validation Application Block error

Tags: .net, poco

After creating this object

```
ClassName obj = new ClassName
{
  Currency = "eur",
  DateStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
  DateEnd = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
};
```

and trying to validate it

```
var validationResults = Validation.Validate<ClassName>(obj);
```

I see this error, and I don't figure out where to look and fix this:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.dll

Additional information: Object must be of type Int32.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here seems to be the problem:

```
[RangeValidator(0f, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 0f, RangeBoundaryType.Ignore, MessageTemplate = "...")]
public virtual double Price
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have decorated some fields or properties of `ClassName` with `Validator` attributes. I assume that some of the attributes are either not applicable or you missed some parameters...